# Running script with parameter when item is clicked

Tags: javascript

If I want to run function something when item is clicked, this script works fine:

```
document.getElementById("item").onclick = something;
```

However, I have problems if I want to pass a parameter to the function using this code:

```
document.getElementById("item").onclick = something('parameter');
```

The function is ran with the parameter when the page first runs, and the script doesn't get called with the item is clicked.

I can do this, which solves my problem:

```
document.getElementById("item").onclick = function(){something('parameter');}
```

But why does the first line of code work whereas the second one fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line works because you are assigning `something`, which is a function, to the `onclick` handler. The `onclick` handler expects a function, which you are correctly supplying.

The second line doesn't work because you are first *invoking* `something`, then assigning *its return value* to the `onclick` handler. If that return value isn't a function, the `onclick` handler won't know what to do with it.

The solution you found is a good solution. It is a specific instance of a method called a "partial," which allows you to prepare parameters before invocation.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `()` to your function, you're essentially invoking it right then and there. The script doesn't recognize that you want to set it equal to an onclick event because it just sees it as you trying to run that function.

That's why you must actually point the onclick event to its own function that just runs the original function that you need

For example `element.onclick = function(...params){...}`

More on JS function invocation:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Answer (score 0):

When ever you put opening and closing braces infront of a function you're actually calling or executing the function.

So when you did id.onclick = function you assigned the function itself to the element.

But when you did id.onclick = function(param) you just executed the function and that time, the element did not store the function.

So it's more adviceable to do it the last way you did it. For example.

id.onclick = function(param){}

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might consider **switching from event handlers to event listeners** (which are generally considered better for several reasons, including versatility.)

**[This tutorial](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events) explains** the difference well.

The contrived example below shows how event listeners work.

Regarding parameters, **the first parameter of the listener is always the event itself**, and the event's `target` property gives us access to the DOM (via the element where the event happened.) So as long as the desired value exists within the DOM, there's no need to provide that value as an explicit argument.

```js
// Identifies elements on the page
const
  item = document.getElementById("item"),
  list = document.getElementById("list");

// Calls addItem when the `item` element is clicked
item.addEventListener("click", addItem);

function addItem(event){

  const
    localReferenceToItem = event.target,
    text = localReferenceToItem.value;  

  if(text === ""){ return; }
  localReferenceToItem.value = "";

  console.log(text);  

  const
    newTextNode = document.createTextNode(text),
    newListItem = document.createElement("li");

  newListItem.appendChild(newTextNode);
  list.appendChild(newListItem);
}
```

```html
<input id="item"/>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```